# How to remove current row from a html table in jQuery json?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, json

I want to write code for `multipledelete` by using jquery json.

This is the jquery code:

```
function DeleteSelected() {
         var categories = new Array();
         debugger;
         // iterate all checkboxes and obtain their checked values, unchecked values are not pushed into array
         $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function ()
             //$('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", this.checked)
         {
             this.checked ? categories.push($(this).val()) : null;
         });

         // assume urldata is your web method to delete multiple records
         var urldata = "WebForm5.aspx/deleteRecord";
         debugger;
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             url: urldata,

             data: "{ 'Id':'"+JSON.stringify( categories)+"' }", // used to convert array into proper JSON format
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (dt) {
                 // done whatever tasks if succeeded
                 alert("entry deleted");
                 debugger;
                 $("#example1").DataTable();
                 //$("#example1").bind;
                 debugger;
             },
             error: function (result) {
                 alert("Error");
             }
         });

     }
```

This is aspx code(codebehind for multiple delete):

```
[WebMethod]
    // note clear difference between single and multiple selections
    public static void deleteRecord(List<int> Id)
    {
        clsCategoryBL objproject = new clsCategoryBL();

        // iterate through input list and pass to process method
        for (int i = 0; i < Id.Count; i++)
        {
            objproject.CategoryDelete(Id[i]);
        }
    }
```

I want to pass the id to aspx page but the problem is that output comes error popup.

```
 error: function (result) {
                 alert("Error");
}
```

Comment: Try replacing `alert("Error")` with `alert(result)` to see what the error is.

Comment: error is [object][Object]

Comment: Use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`

Comment: i want to pass the id to my aspx page but it terurns null show that it goes to return false,so can you tell me how to pass the id? if i used console.log() no popup window..so how to solve?

Comment: looks like syntax error try by replacing `"{ 'Id':'"+JSON.stringify( categories)+"' }"` with `'{"ID":"' + JSON.stringify( categories)+ '"}';`

Comment: @ManojMaharana If you use `console.log(result)` the error object will be displayed in your javascript console.

Comment: no the error is comes once again

Comment: Can anyone post the answer??

Comment: @ManojMaharana Learn how to use your browsers debug tools: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Comment: what is the problem??can you suggest me?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) AND WHEN I CLICK THE LINK THE ERROR POPUP COMES AND LINK IS LIKE WebForm5.aspx/DeleteSelected @Turnip

Comment: @ManojMaharana did you try debugging the `deleteRecord` method? Error code 500 implies something went wrong on the server side..

Comment: Put a debugger in the error sections and when it stops, use the networks tab of the browser console to view the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below line will return JSON for the array `categories`

```
"{ 'Id':'"+JSON.stringify( categories)+"' }"
```

Validate the value with http://jsonlint.com/ and check if the result is valid JSON.

Since you had declared the method as `public static void deleteRecord(List<int> Id)` that means the expected input will be like [1,2,3]

Also use below line to get exact error coming

```
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("error # " + xhr + ajaxOptions + thrownError);
            }
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Below is working code

```
var categories = new Array();
// do your logic to push
categories.push(1);
categories.push(2);
categories.push(3);

var valuetxt = "{ \"Id\":\"" + JSON.stringify(categories) + "\" }";
var urldata = "WebForm1.aspx/deleteRecord";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: urldata,
    data: valuetxt, // used to convert array into proper JSON format
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        // in result you will get same data which is posted
        alert(result.d);

    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("error # " + xhr + ajaxOptions + thrownError);
    }
});


[WebMethod]
// change the parameter to string, convert back  JSON to Integer Array
public static string deleteRecord(string Id)
{
    // do something - for sample here returning same JSON of integer
    return Id;
}
```